# Firebase message received multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase cloudmessaging to grant or revoke users access to the app. 
The revoke message resets the app via following command:

```
(appContext.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).clearApplicationUserData()
```

Restarting the app later firebase generates a new token and after some time I receive the same revokemessage again and the app resets again.
If I send the grant message it gets only sent once.

`clearApplicationUserData()` kills the app right after i receive the message.

Could that cause the problem?

Thanks